# session variable discrepancies between 5.5 and 7

Tags: laravel, php-7

I run PHP 5.5 locally and 7 on live server. The trouble is with laravel session library where I am setting a session variable conditionally and then updating this where relevant. this works like  charm locally, however the variable does not seem to update once set on the live server.

Does anybody know of something like this being affected by PHP 7. This is the only thing I can think of that would affect this bug.

```
if(in_array($currentState, Site::config('config.extra_delivery.'.$countryId.'.values')))
        {
            $newfulfilmentHouse = kohana::config('config.extra_delivery.'.$countryId.'.fulfilmentHouseId');
            Session::set('amendFulfilmentHouse', $newfulfilmentHouse);
            echo true;
        }
        else
        {
            Session::set('amendFulfilmentHouse', $origionalFulfilmentHouse);
            echo true;
        }
```

The I have a very simple ajax call that check with this line:

```
if(Session::get('amendFulfilmentHouse'))$currenctFulfilmentHouse = Session::get('amendFulfilmentHouse');
```

The else in the first function is really just as a back up in logic really. should'nt have any impact. its more based on the config.

Comment: A [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showcasing your problem would help identify it, or at least it will allow us to see if we can reproduce it.

Comment: sorry. updating now.

Comment: So in the method that handles the AJAX call are you expecting the value of the session `amendFulfilmentHouse` key to be the one set from `$newfulfilmentHouse`?

Comment: Make sure the `domain` key is properly set in your `session` config file.

Comment: this is correct @bogdan

Comment: @Mysteryos I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: I'm assuming the Laravel version (which you haven't specified) is above 5.1, as only versions above that support PHP 7 (although older versions down to 4.2 will work, Exception handing will be an issue). Also since you're using conditions involving value taken from configuration files, as well as assigning values taken from configuration files, the obvious question is: are those value what you expect them to be, and are they read correctly when used within the code?

Comment: So what is the value that you're getting from the session: `null`, `$origionalFulfilmentHouse` or some other value? Are you sure the `if` condition block for true is reached at all? And if it is, are you sure the value of `$newfulfilmentHouse` read from that config is the one you expect? In your if statement after you assign the value using `kohana::config`, add this line to log the value that will be set in the session: `\Log::debug('amendFulfilmentHouse', ['value' => $newfulfilmentHouse]);` and then check the log in `storage/logs/laravel.log` to see what was logged.

Comment: Hmm i understand what you are getting at. There is really no point in me doing his locally as it works exactly as I would expect. So I have tested the variables. It does seem to be something with how the sessions are working on the live server.